# Can a Speed roll count as a Might attack?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

My friends and I disagreed playing the zombie attack of Haunt 21.

The rules say that zombies are only killed by attacks from Might weapons. Any other attacks will only stun them.

Some people say that since Speed and Might are both Physical attacks, a Speed attack counts as a Might attack and will kill the zombies.

Specifically, the Revolver says to use a Speed roll "instead of" a Might roll. So we couldn't agree on whether a Revolver would kill a zombie or stun it.

Can anybody weigh in on the specific case of whether a Revolver kills Zombies or, more generally, whether Speed rolls should count as Might rolls?

Comment: When you say role do you mean roll? If so, could you please update the question? As non-native speaker I find it difficult to make sense of it otherwise.

Comment: Yes, it should say "roll".

Answer (score 4):

No, the Revolver cannot kill a zombie.

Speed and Might are 2 completely separate traits, and neither ever counts as the other. Same with Sanity and Intelligence. The fact that there is a higher category called "physical traits" doesn't matter. After all, Intelligence and Might both belong to a higher category called "traits" also.

The rules say specifically:

> You can destroy a Zombie by defeating it in
> combat with any weapon that requires a
> Might attack.

The revolver does not require a Might attack; it requires a Speed attack.